# Cosmos Javascript API for creating collection with Autoscale

Tags: javascript, api, collections, azure-cosmosdb, autoscalemode

I am using `@azure/cosmos` with version `3.9.5` for creating Container and collection in `Cosmos DB`. I am trying to create collection with maxThroughput parameter so that auto scaling will be enabled.

`comosRefClient.database("sample").containers.createIfNotExists({ id: "samplecoll1", 5000 });`

As per documentation, this should create collection with Autoscaling with Max RU of 5000. But collection is created with Manual Mode and 5000 RUs.

I checked in the documentation as well as unit testing code from SDK and ideally things should work fine.

1. API - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/cosmosdb/cosmos/src/client/Container/ContainerRequest.ts
2. Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/containerrequest?view=azure-node-latest
3. Unit Testing from SDK - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/cosmosdb/cosmos/test/public/functional/container.spec.ts

Appreciate your help on this question.

Comment: deployment didn't install the latest library due to unique issue in CI/CD pipeline. After fixing the issue, required version of @azure/cosmos was installed and able to create collection with autoscale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same version with yours. I tried this code and it can work:

```
const { resource: containerDef } = await client.database("sample").containers.createIfNotExists({ id: "samplecoll1",maxThroughput:5000});
```

[image]

Comment: I am checking the deployed libraries in the cloud web app. Will confirm back shortly

Comment: Worked fine with the right library version deployed

Comment: @SMadhanmohan I'm glad to hear that.